# How can I return self in a class method?

Tags: ios, swift, class

Tried this and it gives me an error:

```
class BaseClass {
    class var testProperty: String {
        return "Original"
    }
    class func testingFunc()->Self {
       return self // error - Can not convert return expression of type "Self.Type" to return the type "Self"
    }
}
```

Any thought?
Thanks

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? I think a singleton can help you here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a class/static function, `self` refers to the Class Type. There is no instance to refer to, so what you get is the type, which is the current scope. It's not the same in an instance method, where self refers to `<instance>.self`

```
class Foo {
    class func classMethod() -> Foo.Type {
        return self // means Foo.self
    }

    func instanceMethod() -> Foo {
        return self // means <instance of Foo>.self
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to return an instance of current type from static mathod like: let currentClass:  = self() ; return currentClass ??

Comment: I already answered your question in the gist you published: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44a108093e45db43b6df

The return type will still be `BaseClass`, but as `ChildClass` is a subclass of `BaseClass`, `testProperty` is a known member of the class. It is different if you add a different member in `ChildClass` and you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type should be the class type you are in. In this case it is`BaseClass`.

Also, you are defining a class function which is basically a static function. It will not return an instance. I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But I can refer self inside above mentioned static method like self.testProperty. I'm trying to accomplish a generic base class so if child class is derived from it and I call testingFunc() method from child class, it should return child type with properties and such. Please see the example of what I'm trying to accomplish :https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44a108093e45db43b6df

Comment: Well, you can refer but can't return it the way you think. Types simply do not match, and that gives a compile error. Maybe you can try Self.Type as the return type?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get info about an instance, use an instance function. Omit the keyword `class` when defining the function.

```
class BaseClass {
   func instanceInfo() {
       // self here refers to the instance
   }
}
```